# How do I convert a Java Date into an Instant for a given timezone?

Tags: java, java-time, timezone-offset, java.util.date, java.time.instant

I have an instance of the Date class and a time zone (e.g Europe/London). How do I convert this into an Instant? Is the below the correct way of doing this?

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of(timeZone));
Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
```

Comment: what is an "UTC Instant"? An `Instant` is a "*An instantaneous point on the time-line.*", it does not *have* time zone information. (what about `Instant instant = date.toInstant()`?)

Comment: You don't need a `LocalDateTime`, there's `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant, ZoneId)` where you can put `date.toInstant()` and `ZoneOffset.UTC`. But if you want just a `String`, simply print the `Instant`.

Comment: I've updated that, I just need an Instant.

Comment: `Date.toInstant()`… that's it. It is straight-forward because a `java.util.Date` is not much more than a wrapper around a value representing epoch millis, which is the base of an `Instant`, too.

Comment: BTW that code should not compile, assuming `java.util.Date` or subclasses ("*I have an instance of the Date class*"), because `LocalDateTime.ofInstant()` *requires* an `Instant` (answering "*Is the below the correct way of doing this?*") || BTW2 check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) to find all available methods)

Comment: Which `Date` class did you mean?

Comment: Trying a guess: Are you having a `java.util.Date` that when you print it *appears* to have the date and time that you want in the wanted time zone? For example `Thu May 25 11:44:35 CEST 2023` where you want an `Instant` representing the same moment as `2023-05-25T11:44:35+01:00[Europe/London]`? In this case the `Date` is an incorrect representation of that moment (instant).  Such incorrect representations are sometimes seen exactly because `Date` is so confusing.

Comment: In case my guess is spot-on, your code does make the conversion you asked for.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()
```

No need for `LocalDateTime`, `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime` classes.

## Details

You said:

> I have an instance of the Date class

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = … ;
```

This class is now legacy, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `java.time.Instant`, to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC.

> and a time zone (e.g Europe/London)

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
```

> How do I convert this into an Instant?

No need for the time zone. Both `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant` represent a moment as seen in UTC, as described above.

New  **conversion methods** were added to the *old* classes. Look for the [naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase//tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) of `to…` & `from…`. You can convert back and forth between the legacy classes and the modern classes. Stick to the modern classes. Use the legacy date-time classes only to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*.

```
java.time.Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

And the other direction:

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Beware of data loss in this other direction. An `Instant` has a resolution of nanoseconds, while `java.util.Date` resolves to milliseconds.